# Send data with cURL by post's data

Tags: php, curl

Hi can I concatenate my post data?

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"contact\":{\"dataFields\":[{\"key\":\"FIRSTNAME\",\"value\":\"Foo\"},{\"key\":\"LASTNAME\",\"value\":\"Bar\"}],\"email\":\"foo.bar@gmail.com\",\"optInType\":\"Single\",\"emailType\":\"PlainText\"},\"consentFields\":{\"fields\":[{\"key\":\"UK_OPT_IN_COUNT\",\"value\":\"Y\"}]}}"
```

I need to replace `Foo` with `$_POST['firstName']`, `Bar` with `$_POST['lastName']`, and `foo.bar@gmail.com` with `$_POST['email']`

Comment: build your JSON using json_encode().

Comment: Could you help me a bit of code? Example maybe.

Comment: I mean you _could_ just use standard string concatenation using `.` - did you try anything? But really... don't build JSON by hand, you just open yourself up to making silly syntax errors, or introducing them inadvertently due to the content of the POST data (especially if you don't escape it). And as you can see, that string will be hard to debug due to all the `\ `s cluttering it up. Build an object with the structure and content you need, and then just `json_encode()` it for reliable, easy JSON output.

Comment: `a bit of code`... [are there not enough examples available for you already](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+how+to+use+json_encode)?

Comment: Not for the json @ADyson, but thanks!

Comment: Even this part gave me error `"value\":" . $_POST['firstName'] . "}`

Comment: What error exactly? Like I said, don't bother doing it like this, build your object properly and encode it. That greatly reduces the risk of all kinds of problems, and makes your code neater and easier to maintain, too. There are billions of examples of json_encode usage available, as my link shows.

Comment: Will do that, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Update your question with your new code if you're still having any problems with the task after attempting it.

Answer (score 2):

Found out. I used json encode just like @ADyson suggested. Here is the code if anyone need it:

```
$data = [
    'contact' => [
        'dataFields' => [
            [
                'key' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                'value' => $_POST['firstName']    
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'LASTNAME',
                'value' => $_POST['lastName']  
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'FULLNAME',
                'value' => $_POST['lastName']  
            ]
        ],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'optInType' => 'Single',
        'emailType' => 'PlainText',
    ]
];
```

so you can use like this:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data)
```